# Does ActiveRecord allow force save when validations fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there anyway to force AR to save model changes even when validations fail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, for Rails 3+ with:

```
.save(:validate => false)
```

For Rails 2.3

```
.save(false)
```